# How to update a DATE field when moving PostGIS geometry in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing

I've been correcting our address point file using various methods to identify points that need to be corrected, with the final step being a manual move the point (or by the Numerical Vertex Edit) to its corrected location using QGIS.

What I'd like to do is update the MODIFIED_DATE field automatically when the geometry is moved.

The address points live in PostGIS.

I can see that by setting the Field Edit Widget type to DATE/TIME, and then identifying the point and enabling the 'Auto open form' option, the date will be updated.

But can the date value be updated when the geometry is moved, by some type of dynamic field, or other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger on the date field is what you're looking for.  Here's a good example:

http://www.revsys.com/blog/2006/aug/04/automatically-updating-a-timestamp-column-in-postgresql/

This will allow the database to handle the date updates automatically, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Interesting! Let me try that out and report back! Thank you!